# XUnit aspect-like functionality

Tags: .net, xunit

[WhyDidWeBuildXUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WhyDidWeBuildXunit&referringTitle=Home) article states there is Aspect-Like Functionality which allows to attach some behaviour to test method. I searched any example of it without success. Is there any?

Answer (score 2):

The comment relates to [BeforeAfterTestAttribute](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/Sdk/BeforeAfterTestAttribute.cs).

Here is an example: [automatically roll back database operations](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/AutoRollbackExample/AutoRollbackAttribute.cs).